# TinyMCE data not displaying in jsp properly

Tags: mysql, jsp, struts2, tinymce

i am using TinyMCE for entering texts in a form. When i submit the form with the below input, i am not getting the output in my view jsp as desired.

Texts entered:

**Text in Bold**. *Text in Italic*

Its a new paragraph

The texts are getting saved in the database as below(as viewed under MySql workbench). The datatype for the attribute in database is TEXT.

```
<p><strong>Text in Bold</strong>. <em>Text in Italic</em>.</p><p>Its a new paragraph</p>
```

And in my jsp too, it is displaying in the same way like:

`<p><strong>Text in Bold</strong>. <em>Text in Italic</em>.</p><p>Its a new paragraph</p>`

When i view the jsp source, i get this:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Text in Bold&lt;/strong&gt;. &lt;em&gt;Text in Italic&lt;/em&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Its a new paragraph&lt;/p&gt;
```

I am displaying the texts in my jsp using a Struts Iterator using tag:

```
<s:property value="description"/>
```

TinyMCE initialization code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link",
    plugins: [
                   "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                   "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
                   "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor "
             ]
});
```

How to solve this problem and display the texts in jsp with the format used while typing in TinyMCE text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `escapeHtml` attribute of `<s:property>` tag.

```
<s:property value="description" escapeHtml="false"/>
```